# Трудности с кодом javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, возможно и вопрос слишком прост, но чето уже долго не могу понять как сделать. 
Есть код упрощенно вот такой

```
<li onclick='alert()'><span id='лала'></span></li>
```

Вот что надо написать в алерт что бы при нажатии вылезло "лала".

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].id
```

Вот только не пойму, зачем это вам.

Comment: честно долгая история связанная с прототайпом

Answer (score 1):

Без JQuery так:

```
...
<li onclick="liClick(this)"><span id="span-id-no-1"></span></li>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function liClick (e) {
        alert (e.childNodes[0].id);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `childNodes` - лучше не использовать ( в нём ещё есть текстовые ноды ), надо брать из `childen` либо использовать `firstElementChild`

Comment: Согласен. Только вот что с совместимостью ? см. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html Либо, таки, придется использовать JQuery

Comment: так `children[0]`  -  кроссбраузерно, вроде как)

Answer (score 1):

Всего-то

```
<li onclick='alert(this.firstChild.id)'><span id='лала'></span></li>
```